# The bot gives an error when using the "with" operator

Tags: python

i've come across this error. Found on the Internet based on discord.py code to create YouTube alerts on the server. When starting the bot, the system encounters a syntax error and points to the "with" operator. Previously, this operator has already been used in the code and did not give errors.
Please help those who know.
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0K4F.jpg
Code:

````
async def newvideo(): #система оповещений ютуб
    with open("youtubeuser.json", "r") as f:
        data=json.load(f)

    print(" All systems online. Searching new vids...")

    for youtube_channel in data:

        channel = f"https://www.youtube.com/channel/{youtube_channel}"

        html = requests.get(channel+"/videos").text

        try:
            latest_video_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + re.search('(?<="videoId":").*?(?=")', html).group() #!Разобраться в смысле этого кода

        except:
            continue 
        #это типо как if else, только круче!

        if not str(data[youtube_channel]["latest_video_url"]) == latest_video_url:

            data[str [youtube_channel]['latest_video_url'] == latest_video_url

                with open("youtubeuser.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(data, f)

            discord_channel_id = data[str(youtube_channel)]['notifying_discord_channel']
            discord_channel = bot.get_channel(int(discord_channel_id))

            msg = f"Хэй! На канале {data[str(youtube_channel)]['channel_name']} происходит какой-то движ! Наши системы уловили что-то интересное. Бегом смотреть! \n"
            "{latest_video_url}"

            await discord_channel.send(msg)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error is on the line *before* the `with` statement:

```
        data[str [youtube_channel]['latest_video_url'] == latest_video_url
```

This has unbalanced brackets, and generally doesn't make any sense. Fix that error and the `with` statement will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you. Due to my inattention, I did not close the brackets, apparently due to the fact that I usually write code at night)